# Archivos en PHP - Sumar solo números

Tags: php

Este código guarda en un archivo txt una serie de datos, necesito sumar los valores y discriminar el string.

Me ayudaís?

Gracias!

```
<?php

$data1 = fopen("archivo.txt", "w");

fputs($data1, "27 \n" );
fputs($data1, "casa \n");
fputs($data1, "51 \n");

fclose($data1);

$data2 = fopen("archivo.txt", "r");

while (!feof($data2)){
    $linea = fgets($data2);

 }


fclose($data2);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar con algo así, cada línea eliminas el \n y si es numérico haces la suma.

```html
<?php

$data1 = fopen("archivo.txt", "w");
fputs($data1, "27 \n" );
fputs($data1, "casa \n");
fputs($data1, "51 \n");
fclose($data1);

$data2 = fopen("archivo.txt", "r");
$sum = 0;
while (!feof($data2))
{
    $linea = fgets($data2);
    $data = trim(str_replace("\n","",$linea));
    if (is_numeric($data)) { $sum = $sum + floatval($data);}
}

fclose($data2);
```

Comment: Gracias Vicent, me resuelve mi problema

Comment: Si te sirve recuerda marcarlo como respuesta